# How do I avoid multiple query for Pagination count and data retreival?

Tags: sql, database, pagination

I have a scenario where I get a count and then pass the count as a variable to a similar query to get the paginated records. So basically I am doing a full query to get all the count by internally creating the full table and then using that count to display the same table with 10 per page. What solutions do I have to avoid this sort of multiple query?

Something like this is a Pseudo language .

```
select count {big table}

select big table where records are between count and count+10
```

Is there a sensible way to get the COUNT variable in the same query?

I am wondering how would Google handle a search, would it first find all the records or just fetch the records without tracking the no: of pages? Page numbers can't be computed prior as it is dependent on the variable sent by the user.

Edit: I have a similar question here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161586/including-count-of-a-result-in-the-main-query

Comment: That pseudo-query makes no sense. If `count` holds the number of rows in the table then `between count and count+10` won't return anything.

Comment: count+1 then . thanks . count keeps track of the page no:S

Comment: So does `count` refer to the number of rows in the table or the current page number?

Comment: count refers to page no: Say there are 30 records , count would give me 3 .

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't follow. My understanding is that you would want to pass in a page number, say 2, and then return the 10 records for that page, e.g. records 10-19. But you seem to be asking for something else.

Comment: Yes we just sent like 1 2 3 , meaning page no:s to the second query which is just a subset of the first one . First one finds all the records to get a count of how many records are there ..Basically my problem is that we are duplicating queries ...Using a big query to find the full table ...getting the count ...and then senting filter to get the 10 records at a time . Why cant we just use the count query to get all the data ... because we are generating a big table anyway .

Comment: What DBMS are you using? A `COUNT` query is relatively inexpensive in processing terms. If you're wanting to return both the number of pages (number of records divided by 10) and the records for the current page then you're going to need 2 queries - they are 2 distinct sets of data.

Comment: You are talking about "creating/generating" a table. What table are you creating?

Comment: Imagine , google search and I enter England ... would google first compute all the results for England in one shot and then sent 10 a time to user . Or does it just find 10 records and sent to them ? If they are finding all the record in one shot its a big table ...But if they dont do that how do they get the COUNT ? Thats the question I have

Comment: "Why cant we just use the count query to get all the data" - how would that be returned? What would the resultset look like?

Comment: A count query doesnt generate a big table ? It takes the same input as  records fetching ... with a page filter . Using MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: They would perform a `COUNT` query first, and then perform a second query to retrieve the records for the specified page. Bear in mind that Google uses very advanced algorithms for indexing data - they do not search their entire database on-the-fly.

Comment: MSSQL relates to SQL Server. Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Correct ,so I have a doubt - isn't COUNT as expensive as fetching the full data ? We need to generate the full table isnt it ? To get the count list ? (We use both MSSQL and ORACLE for Production uses )

Comment: You are not "generating a full table" - that implies you are inserting data. You aren't. You are retrieving data. `COUNT` is not as expensive as you aren't retrieving the data, you are merely obtaining a count of how many records a table contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Google, they are likely to generate only the requested amount of results (like 10) and to estimate the count. The estimated count is *very* imprecise.

You can't have SQL Server count all results and get only a subset of them. There 3 strategies to deal with this:

- execute a counting and a data query
- execute an unlimited data query and discard all but ten results on the client
- execute an unlimited data query into a temp-table whose primary key is the row number. You can then count instantly (get the last row) and select any subset by rownumber with a single seek

Counting the data can be significantly cheaper because SQL Server can use different indexes or discard joins.